# Minimum Size Subarray Sum with sorting

Tags: arrays, sum

The Minimum Size Subarray Sum problem:

given an array of n positive integers and a positive integer s, find the minimal length of a subarray of which the sum ≥ s. If there isn't one, return 0 instead.

For example, given the array [2,3,1,2,4,3] and s = 7,
the subarray [4,3] has the minimal length under the problem constraint.

The following is my solution:

```
public int minSubArrayLen(int s, int[] nums) {

    long sum = 0;
    int a = 0;
    if (nums.length < 1)
        return 0;
    Arrays.sort(nums);

    for (int i = nums.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sum += nums[i];
        a++;
        if (sum>=s)
            break;
    }

    if (sum < s) {
        return 0;
    }

    return a;
}
```

This solution was not accepted because it did not pass the following test case:

697439

[5334,6299,4199,9663,8945,3566,9509,3124,6026,6250,7475,5420,9201,9501,38,5897,4411,6638,9845,161,9563,8854,3731,5564,5331,4294,3275,1972,1521,2377,3701,6462,6778,187,9778,758,550,7510,6225,8691,3666,4622,9722,8011,7247,575,5431,4777,4032,8682,5888,8047,3562,9462,6501,7855,505,4675,6973,493,1374,3227,1244,7364,2298,3244,8627,5102,6375,8653,1820,3857,7195,7830,4461,7821,5037,2918,4279,2791,1500,9858,6915,5156,970,1471,5296,1688,578,7266,4182,1430,4985,5730,7941,3880,607,8776,1348,2974,1094,6733,5177,4975,5421,8190,8255,9112,8651,2797,335,8677,3754,893,1818,8479,5875,1695,8295,7993,7037,8546,7906,4102,7279,1407,2462,4425,2148,2925,3903,5447,5893,3534,3663,8307,8679,8474,1202,3474,2961,1149,7451,4279,7875,5692,6186,8109,7763,7798,2250,2969,7974,9781,7741,4914,5446,1861,8914,2544,5683,8952,6745,4870,1848,7887,6448,7873,128,3281,794,1965,7036,8094,1211,9450,6981,4244,2418,8610,8681,2402,2904,7712,3252,5029,3004,5526,6965,8866,2764,600,631,9075,2631,3411,2737,2328,652,494,6556,9391,4517,8934,8892,4561,9331,1386,4636,9627,5435,9272,110,413,9706,5470,5008,1706,7045,9648,7505,6968,7509,3120,7869,6776,6434,7994,5441,288,492,1617,3274,7019,5575,6664,6056,7069,1996,9581,3103,9266,2554,7471,4251,4320,4749,649,2617,3018,4332,415,2243,1924,69,5902,3602,2925,6542,345,4657,9034,8977,6799,8397,1187,3678,4921,6518,851,6941,6920,259,4503,2637,7438,3893,5042,8552,6661,5043,9555,9095,4123,142,1446,8047,6234,1199,8848,5656,1910,3430,2843,8043,9156,7838,2332,9634,2410,2958,3431,4270,1420,4227,7712,6648,1607,1575,3741,1493,7770,3018,5398,6215,8601,6244,7551,2587,2254,3607,1147,5184,9173,8680,8610,1597,1763,7914,3441,7006,1318,7044,7267,8206,9684,4814,9748,4497,2239]

The expected answer is 132 but my output was 80.

Does anyone have any idea what went wrong with my algorithm/code?

Comment: The biggest issue in your code is you are taking some in linear fashion. That is you take the sum of first 3 or first 5 to determine if sum is greater than s. You need to consider if you take the numbers in random order and get the sum near to s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will simply explain the flaw in the logic rather giving the correct logic to handle the problem statement

You are taking the numbers in a specific sequence and then adding them for comparison. Quite easily the case can be different where you take numbers in random order to get the exact sum.

For example [2,3,1,2,4,3] and s = 7.

Based on your logic
Step 1-> Sort the numbers and you get [1,2,2,3,3,4]
Step 2-> You pick last 2 number (3,4) to get your sum 7

Lets change the sum to 8
From Step 2-> You get 3+3+4 = 10 so u break out of the loop. After this step you return a = 2

Flaw here is 4+3+1 also makes 8 something your logic skips.
Same way 3+3+2 is also possible solution to achieve 8.

You sorting the array is first flaw in the logic itself. If you consider subarray of existing arrangement, sorting changes the arrangement therefore you will never be able to get the expected solution.